# Android studio navigation drawer with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Hello i'm not an expert in android development. I'm trying to develop an application using the Navigation drawer template of Android Studio. So, i created a new project using this template. But when i run the program an click on a menu item, the view doesn't change. So i searched everywhere on internet i didn't see how i can handle this. 
This is the code provided by studio

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.

int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {


} else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

} else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

}

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
return true;
```

}

What i want to achieve is to replace the current view with the appropriate view which menu's is cliked.

Comment: your question is about , how to call a fragment which  has no connection with navigation drawer (only you get the id of a drawer item)

,in your if else condition .. do a fragment transaction..and attach a new fragment to your frame.. search how to do that!

Comment: because i was searched, and try the instruction, still not happen anything... so i post my question in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Gallery.Java and paste this code:

```
public class Gallery extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery,null);
    }


}
```

And in your navigation drawer file paste this code:

```
 if (id == R.id.nav_gallery)
        {
            Fragment fragment = new Gallery();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment).commit();
        }
```